# implement dropout layer using nn.Sequential()

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to implement a Dropout layer using pytorch as follows:

```
class DropoutLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, p):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = p

    def forward(self, input):
        if self.training:
            u1 = (np.random.rand(*input.shape)<self.p) / self.p
            u1 *= u1
            return u1
        else:
            input *= self.p
```

And then calling a simple NN.sequential:

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_size,num_classes), DropoutLayer(.7), nn.Flatten())

opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.005)
train(model, opt, 5) #train(model, optimizer, epochs #)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: flatten() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Still new to pytorch.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the `forward` function of your `DropoutLayer`, when you enter the `else`branch, there is no return. Therefore the following layer (`flatten`) will have no input. However, as emphasized in the comments, that's not the actual problem.

The actual problem is that you are passing a numpy array to your `Flatten` layer. A Minimal code to reproduce the problem would be :

```
nn.Flatten()(np.random.randn(5,5))
>>> TypeError: flatten() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

However, I cannot explain why this layer behaves like that on a numpy tensor, the behavior of the `flatten` **function** being much more understandable. I don't know what additional operations the layer performs.

```
torch.flatten(np.random.randn(5,5))
>>> TypeError: flatten(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray
```

Why this error is raised by your code is because in the forward pass, you create a numpy tensor, perform some operations, and return it instead of returning a tensor. If I may, you don't even touch the actual input tensor (in the first branch)

Comment: it still gives the same error..train() automatically sets the model to training and thus the if() statemetn in fwd evals to true

Comment: yep my bad, I was not adressing the actual issue, this is now corrected :)

Answer (score -1):

The code is resolved and the solution was simply calling in `nn.Sequential(Flatten())` first to augment the input matrix to a `nx786` dimension.

Comment: You might want to consider accepting your answer if this solved your problem.