# Writing a dropout layer using nn.Sequential() method + Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to create a Dropout Layer for my neural network using nn.Sequential() like this:

```
class DropoutLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, p):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = p
    def forward(self, input):
        if self.training:
            u1 = (np.random.rand(*input.shape)<self.p) 
            u1 *= input
            return u1
        else:
            input *= self.p
model = nn.Sequential(Flatten(),DropoutLayer(p = 0.7),nn.LogSoftmax(dim = -1))
opt = torch.optim.Adam(modelDp.parameters(), lr=0.005)
train(modelDp, opt, 5)
```

But I get this error:
ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

Comment: There is nothing in this code that can produce this error. The 784x10 shape lets me think you are working on MNIST, with a Linear layer, and I believe this layer is failing. Are you using a batch size of 128 and made a mistake with a `view`?  In addition to this, the code is weirdly similar to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032525/implement-dropout-layer-using-nn-sequential/64032837#64032837 . Can I ask where do this code comes from ?

Comment: it is homework for deep learning. yes I am using a batch size of 128 and using Flatten()                                                                                                                 ```class Flatten(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return x.view(x.size()[0], -1)```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is what I assume to be a small typo : you declare `model = nn.Sequential(...)` but then use `modelDp.parameters()`. I assume you just made a small copypaste mistake and these are actually the same thing.

This error is yielded because no layer in your model has trainable parameters, i.e parameters that will be affected by the gradient backpropagation step. Actually, this "network" cannot learn anything at all.

To get rid of the error and get an actual working neural network, you need to include the learning layers, which according to the previous error you had reported, are linear layers. That would be something like :

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784, 10), Flatten(), DropoutLayer(0.7), nn.LogSoftMax(dim=-1))
```

Now a couple additional remarks :

- You may want to use the pytorch random tensors instead of Numpy's. It will be easier to deal with the `device`when you will eventually want to move your network on GPU.
- This code is going to yield another error as soon as you try it in `eval` mode because your second conditional branch in the `forward` method does not return anything. You may want to replace the instruction with `return input * self.p`